# Data race when using Gock with HTTP calls in goroutine

Tags: testing, go, race-condition

I am mocking my HTTP calls during tests with Gock and it works well unless I run the HTTP call from a separate goroutine (think `go Post("https://myapi.com", "this body"`). I don't really care about the HTTP response in this case and just want to fire the request.

This results in a race condition between `http.Client.send()` and `gock.New()`. Is there a way around it or what is the recommended way to mock the API calls in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Without source code, its hard to find the problem. How was your configuration? Single `gock` vs single request in separate goroutine or single vs many?

Comment: Hi, it's a single mock for a single request. However, as I was preparing a code sample I noticed, that the data race was most likely caused by the deferred `gock.Off()` being executed too early - since the test itself was effectively over by the time the request was fired in the goroutine.

The solution which worked in this case was to add a short sleep before `gock.Off()`.

Comment: I think short sleep is not guaranteed to work for all condition. You should use synchronization e.g. [using channel](https://gobyexample.com/channel-synchronization). What is the purpose of performing request in separate goroutine? Gock's interceptor may be closed before your request is completed.

Comment: The main idea is to receive a payload on the microservice API endpoint and if it's valid, run the processing job in another goroutine while returning 202 with the jobID immediately. The job can take seconds or even minutes and after it's done it fires a POST request to the main API with the report. That's the call I'm trying to mock.

I believe that the sleep is more of a hotfix than a real solution, but implementing channels just for the sake of testing seems like an overkill. Or is it not?

Comment: @HRcc Have you solved this issue by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`TestMain`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Main) with the following construct:

```
func setup() {
    //Mock microservice
    gock.New("...")

    // JOB finished URI
    // Mock: go Post("https://myapi.com", "this body")
    gock.New("...")
    // other setup
}

func cleanup() {
    //Wait until all mock done/timeout
    //Adjust as needed
    timeoutSec := 10
    for timeoutSec > 0 && gock.IsPending() {
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        timeoutSec--
    }
}

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    defer gock.Off()

    setup()
    ret := m.Run()
    if ret == 0 {
        cleanup()
    }

    os.Exit(ret)
}

func TestYourService(t *testing.T) {
    //Perform testing:  
    //  access microservice + job in separate goroutine
}
```